# PrimeNG confirmation dialog (OverLay) has no build-in style (css)

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I added a PrimeNG confirmation dialog (followed the example from the official doc):

component.html

```
<p-confirmDialog appendTo="body" #cd>
     <p-footer>
        <button type="button" pButton class="btn btn-primary btn-normal mr-4" label="Print or save" (click)="cd.accept()"></button>
        <button type="button" pButton class="btn btn-default btn-normal ml-2" label="Skip" (click)="cd.reject()"></button>
    </p-footer>
</p-confirmDialog>
```

component.ts:

```
import { ConfirmationService } from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
    selector: 'xxx',
    templateUrl: './xxx.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./xxx.component.scss'],
    providers: [ConfirmationService]
})
constructor(private _confirmationService: ConfirmationService) { }

// I am trying to simplify the code
// this method is called successfully 
this._confirmationService.confirm({
   message: 'Please print or save the confirmation details before continuing.',
   header: 'Confirmation details',
   accept: () => {
        this.navigatetoPaymentApp();
   }
});
```

angular.json:

```
 "styles": [              
          "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
          "src/styles/main.scss"
        ],
```

app.module.ts:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        //...
    ],
    //...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And I got this:

[image]

The expected result is like this:
[image]

Issues:
1. missing out-of-box styling from primeng (e.g. darken background)
2. missing close window cross icon

Is there anything missing?
Ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I found the issue. It's because the CSS styles are coming from the prime theme. e.g. add `"node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css"` to angular.json for the styles list.

So I implemented the following classes with specific properties:

```
.ui-confirmdialog.ui-dialog {
    width: 34em;
    background-color: white;

    & .ui-dialog-titlebar {
        padding: .5em 0.667em;
        font-family: xxx;
        font-size: 1.3125rem;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: orange;
    }

    & .ui-dialog-content {
        padding: 1em;
    }
}
```

Additionally, I need to add this to darken the background (I drew some wisdom from the theme.css files from primeNG:

```
body .ui-widget-overlay {
    background-color: #424242;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
}
```

Note: the class `ui-widget-overlay` is pretty much empty if theme is not applied.